# iOS and bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I want to develop an app which will communicate with devices via bluetooth. I am not able to find any tutorial to help me with this. I don't mean bluetooth 4.0 LE but classic bluetooth. All I have found is CoreBluetooth framework but I think this is only for bluetooth LE. I have found also something like IOBluetooth and IOBluetoothUI but I am not sure if it is for Mac OS or for iOS. But still can't find any tutorial or something to help me understand whole process (discovering, establish connection, communication,...). Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 10):

OK so I just found this [article](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/07/bluetooth-and-ios-use-bluetooth-in-your-iphone-apps/#.UahOYZUeVeW).

According to this article there are 5 ways how to work with Bluetooth:

1. **Enroll MFI program** - expensive and long period process
2. **CoreBluetooth framework** - works only with Bluetooth 4.0 LE devices
3. **GameKit framework** - only for iOS device (two iPhones) so you can't work with other device then with iOS
4. **Private API** - app with private API won't be approved by Apple on the Appstore
5. **Jailbreak**

It seems there isn't normal official way how to work with bluetooth.

My case: I want to communicate with not iOS device which has bluetooth 2.1 and I want to have it on the app store -> I can use only first one so I am screwed...

Comment: What kind of device particularly?

Comment: Sensing device, the company where I work is manufacturer of it. But I don´t understand how the enrollment of MFI program will help me to develop app? They will provide me some API after enrollment?

Comment: No. The MFI programs allows you (the company/manufacturer of the device) to put the logo "Made for iPhone" on the packaging (IE. Apple certifies that it works with iOS correctly). It  also guarantee that your app talking with this device can be put on the AppStore.
You still work with ExternalAccessory.framework. I hope also that your device correspond to the profile authorized by Apple for Bluetooth...

Comment: What you mean by "your device correspond to the profile authorized by Apple for Bluetooth" ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/BluetoothDesignGuidelines.pdf & http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Comment: Don´t say that if there isn´t SPP profile it means we can´t do that.

Comment: Hey @DanielH, I also want to connect one of the bluetooth device to iOS app. Please help me with this.

Comment: Hey @Larme Please help me to connect bluetooth device to iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out GameKit's bluetooth feature. A basic tutorial [here](http://vivianaranha.com/apple-gamekit-bluetooth-integration-tutorial/)

Also you can check Ray Wenderlich's tutorial which is a bit more enchanced one. Can be found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12).

Comment: It seems that bluetooth feature of GameKit is only for communication between two iPhones. I want to communicate with peripheral devices (they have bluetooth adapter 2.1)...