# CoreBluetooth and BluetoothManager, device is not BLE

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Connect and receive data via bluetooth.

We are developing an app for a client. It is a toy for babies that connects via bluetooth and we're having trouble connecting and transferring data.

After all the research we did, we found two alternatives: **CoreBluetooth and BluetoothManager**. As far as I know CoreBluetooth only connects with Bluetooth Low Energy (I think it is the latest bluetooth version) and with it I am not able to find my client's device. With the second option, BluetoothManager i can find the device but I can not transfer data.

This makes me think that my **client device is not BLE**. Is there any way to connect and transfer data with this device, considering that **CoreBluetooth doesn't locate the device and only BluetoothManager** does?

Could you please provide alternatives and/or examples of how to make this communication? And if you can not do, let me know in order to tell my client.

Comment: `BluetoothManager`? Is that on the Android part? If you want "classical Bluetooth", I'd strongly suggest you to look at the MFi Program, and its framework: ExternalAccessory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To communicate with lower versions of Bluetooth you need to use ExternalAccessory framework, but it is for MFi devices, so I guess you need to sign to Apple MFi Program: https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

This answer describes possible ways of working with Bluetooth on iOS:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16852224/4495995

Answer (score 2):

CoreBluetooth is only intended to connect to devices equipped with Bluetooth Low Energy. Which while it does share some concepts with its namesake, is a completely different technology. So as of Bluetooth 4.0 we have:

1. Low Energy (or Smart) - slower, simpler, energy efficient
2. Basic Rate / Extended Data Rate (or Classic, High Speed, Smart Ready) - older, more complex, faster, less energy efficient

It seems that because of the energy efficiency as a normal developer you are only allowed to use BLE. If you want to use BR/EDR you need to apply for to the MFi Program, and use special hardware.

Comment: Wondering if you would have to be apart of the MFI program to develop an app not posted on the store that uses BR/EDR ?