# iOS app development for a classic bluetooth device

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, mfi

We are developing an android and ios mobile app for a hardware device. We have to read files generated from the device and move it to mobile app. The device is not a low energy device. It's a Bluetooth 2.1. Currently, we are unable to pair the device with the iPhone. 
We need to understand is there any restriction to connect the iphone with classic Bluetooth devices?  Does the manufacture need to register under MFI?  Can we use some developer license/API to start developing the app and later we go for MFI?

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Please refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473059/corebluetooth-and-bluetoothmanager-device-is-not-ble

To deal with non BLE devices you need to sign to Apple MFi Program

Comment: The developer and the manufacturer need to be MFi licensees. The hardware needs to contain specific MFi chips to work with iOS. Developer licensees can get access to limited number of chips for development purposes. The manufacturing licensees gets access to production quantities.