# Core Bluetooth Classic in MAUI

Tags: ios, .net, bluetooth, maui, core-bluetooth

I need to connect to some classic Bluetooth devices (BT version 2), in a Maui application.
On Android everything already works well, the problematic part is the iOS application. Unfortunately the devices I need to connect to are not certified by the MFI program, so I can connect to them only using the functions of Core Bluetooth Classic (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/using_core_bluetooth_classic).

Unfortunately I don't find any way to do that because:

- The native CoreBluetooth Namespace of MAUI seems to work only with Bluetooth BLE (version 4 and above);
- The library 32feet.NET (https://github.com/inthehand/32feet) is working with BT 2.0 but is using EAAccessoryManager (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory/eaaccessorymanager), not Core Bluetooth Classic;
- I can't find a different library or a connection from Core Bluetooth Classic that I can use in MAUI.

Anyone can help me to find a way to do that?

Thanks,
Michele

Comment: iOS does not allow to work with Classic Bluetooth devices if that device was not developed for Apple (https://inthehand.com/2022/12/15/12-days-of-bluetooth-6-bluetooth-classic-on-ios/)

Comment: Core Bluetooth Classic allows you to work with BR/EDR peripherals but only using the GATT profile. If your peripherals use another profile, such as SPP, they are not supported.

Comment: Does this help?[CoreBluetooth and BluetoothManager, device is not BLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473059/corebluetooth-and-bluetoothmanager-device-is-not-ble)

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT , thanks, helped. And seems like there's no way to use the device...

Comment: I totally agree with you.