# App connecting with Iheath BP7 device BLE

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I want to write application IOS and use IHealth BP7 device BLE.
In the delegate of `CBCentralManager` i didn't receive the BP7 device.
Someone know if it is possible to write BLE app with datas from the BP7 device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well, no wonder you can't connect to iHealth BP7 **as it doesn't even have BLE.**

It has Bluetooth V3.0 as the [official doc](http://www.ihealthlabs.com/files/2914/0192/1721/wireless_bloodpressure_wrist_UserManual.pdf) states:

> Wireless Communication: Bluetooth V3.0 + EDR Class 2 SPP

You have limited options if you want use regular bluetooth on iOS. More here:

[iOS and bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839400/ios-and-bluetooth)