# Connecting an iPhone app to a PC app via Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am currently researching the possibilities of connecting an iPhone app to a windows app via Bluetooth.

The Windows App is written in C# and uses Serial ports to transfer Data. Windows allow me to connect a serial port to Bluetooth. This setup allows communication via Serial over Bluetooth.
I know this setup works because I have managed to communicate with this setup from an Android phone.

I don't seem to be able to do the same with an iPhone 5s (I can't even seem to pair the iPhone to the Windows PC). I haven't been able to test this with a more recent iPhone, but I don't expect it to work either since it's an Apple device with a Windows machine.

I've done some research regarding the possibilities of connecting an iPhone to something else (like a PC) over Bluetooth, and it doesn't seem to be possible.
I have found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839400/ios-and-bluetooth/16852224#16852224) which seems to say that I cannot use Bluetooth Classic to connect an iPhone to a PC.

Since I can't seem to be able to use Bluetooth Classic, I have also tried to use BLE, but I haven't worked out how to simulate the PC as a "peripheral device" to connect to it from the iPhone. I don't even know if that's possible.

So basically my questions are:

**1) Is it possible to communicate via Bluetooth between an iPhone and a PC?**

**2) Would it be possible to use some sort of adapter for the iPhone to connect to the PC (For example, an Arduino with a Bluetooth chip, acting as a BLE peripheral, and sending the data to the PC?)**

**3) What alternative would I have to this? I know WiFi might work, but I am uncertain if the PC running the app will be network enabled when the project goes live.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect an iPhone with PC over Bluetooth using BLE.

I tried with Linux machine (Ubuntu 16.04 with BLE dongle 4.0) which acts as BLE Peripheral and iPhone 8 with BLE 5.0 as central application. Both could able to successfully communicate using custom GATT service that we developed. The throughput i observed here was 2.5 kiloBytes per sec.

If you are so specific on Windows to act as BLE Peripheral, then i believe there are apps available in Windows store to download which enables Windows PC to act as peripheral. Once peripheral mode is enabled, you can always communicate to this over BLE using iPhone [recommended latest phones]. But you need to try this out.

Comment: Does any BLE dongle allow for emulating BLE Peripheral? The windows tools I found don't seem to allow me to do that, and I wonder if it's the dongle's fault.

Comment: you can check if your dongle supports BLE by - Right click on "My Computer" (desktop) -> Device manager -> expand to see the bluetooth driver. Details can be found here: https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-check-if-your-pc-supports-bluetooth-4-0/

Comment: Thank you. Turns out the dongle I have doesn't support it.

Comment: OK. You have to use Bluetooth 4.0 at least to support low energy.

Comment: Looks like it's got 4.0, but not BLE? which is odd, but it's also got some non-standard BT drivers (BlueSoleil).
Thanks for your help anyway, it's good to know that it is possible, even if I don't currently have the right hardware.