Unable to scan devices in iOS
I have create a small application where trying to connect with devices via bluetooth but here I can't see all devices (mobile, earphone...) in scanned devices list except of my laptop (mac) only. And also it's not showing device name in list (only show mac after connecting with device).
And it's showing Mac device two times with different id.
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Alert, Button, FlatList, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {BleManager, Device, ScanMode} from 'react-native-ble-plx';

const ble = new BleManager();
function App() {
  const [devices, setDevices] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [connected, setConnectedIds] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    ble.onStateChange(async state => {
      console.log(state);
    });
  }, []);

  const isDuplicateDevice = (devices: Device[], nextDevice: Device) =>
    devices.findIndex(device => nextDevice.id === device.id) > -1;

  const startScane = async () => {
    await ble.startDeviceScan(
      null,
      {scanMode: ScanMode.LowLatency},
      async (_err, device) => {
        if (device) {
          // @ts-ignore
          delete device._manager;
          setDevices(items => {
            if (!isDuplicateDevice(items, device)) {
              return [...items, device];
            }
            return items;
          });
        }
      },
    );
  };

  const stopScane = async () => {
    await ble.stopDeviceScan();
  };

  const clearAll = async () => {
    setConnectedIds([]);
    setDevices([]);
    await stopScane();
  };

  const handleConnect = async (device: any) => {
    try {
      await ble.connectToDevice(device.id);
      setConnectedIds([...connected, device.id]);
      // getConnected();
      Alert.alert('Device connected');
    } catch (error: any) {
      Alert.alert('Device connection error', error.message);
    }
  };

  const deviceDisconnect = async (device: any) => {
    try {
      await ble.cancelDeviceConnection(device.id);
      setConnectedIds(connected.filter(item => item !== device.id));
      // getConnected();
      Alert.alert('Device disconnected');
    } catch (error: any) {
      Alert.alert('Device disconnection error', error.message);
    }
  };
  const renderDeviceItem = ({item}: any) => {
    const isConnected = connected.includes(item.id);
    const action = isConnected ? deviceDisconnect : handleConnect;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: connected.includes(item.id)
            ? 'lightgreen'
            : 'lightgrey',
          marginBottom: 10,
          padding: 10,
          borderRadius: 10,
        }}>
        <Text>Device Name: {item.name}</Text>
        <Text>Device ID: {item.id}</Text>
        <Text>Can connect: {item.isConnectable ? 'Yes' : 'No'}</Text>
        {item.isConnectable && (
          <Button
            onPress={() => action(item)}
            title={isConnected ? 'Disconnect' : 'Connect'}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={{paddingTop: 50, paddingHorizontal: 10}}>
      <Button title="Scan" onPress={startScane} />
      <Button title={`Stop Scan ${devices.length}`} onPress={stopScane} />
      <Button title={`Clear all`} onPress={clearAll} />
      <FlatList
        style={{maxHeight: 700}}
        data={devices}
        key={connected.length}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={renderDeviceItem}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;



Welcome to Stack Overflow. With 'scan' you are only scanning for Bluetooth LE devices. If you want to find Bluetooth classic devices, you need to run the discovery() procedure. Device name advertisment is optional in Bluetooth LE.

@Risto How can I scan classic devices, I tried many packages but was unable to setup this?

Bluetooth classic devices are discovered. Apple is extremely picky about this technology. A long list of answers can be found here. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839400/ios-and-bluetooth/16852224#16852224
